# Стоит ли использовать стек?

Tags: c++

У меня есть классы, использующие стек для хранения данных. Сейчас пишу новый, который будет занимать 4Кб на стеке. Это делается для того, чтобы уменьшить количество операций с памятью. Если объем данных, хранящихся этим классом, будет менее 4кб, обращений к функциям выделения памяти не будет вообще.

Правилен ли такой подход, хранить данные на стеке?

Comment: Что такое "классы, использующие стек для хранения данных"??? Каким обращзом класс может "исползовать стек"? О чем именно идет речь? О каком "стеке"?

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, постановка вопроса довольно странная. Что такое "класс, использующий стек"? Класс не имеет никакого контроля над тем, в какой памяти будут храниться его *непосредственные* члены. Этот контроль - полностью в руках того, кто будет определять объекты этого класса. Если объект класса определен локально, то он будет жить в автоматической памяти (т.е. в стеке). Если объект класса определен на уровне namespace, то он будет жить в статической памяти. Если объект класса размещен в динамической памяти, то он будет жить в динамической памяти. Поэтому смысл вашей фразы "класс, использующий стек" мне в упор не ясен. Как им это образом у вас класс "использует стек для хранения данных"?

Может вы ведете речь о том, что просто написали большой по размеру класс и волнуетесь, что кто-то будет определять объекты вашего класса в стеке? Ну так, еще раз, это не ваша забота. Это забота того, кто потом будет определять объекты вашего класса. Если они кому-то кажутся слишком большими для стека, то никто им не запрещает создавать ваши объекты в каком-то другом типе памяти.

Во-вторых, понятно, что помещать огромные объекты в стек чревато переполнением стека. Но что такое "огромные"? Для современной рабочей станции 4К - это детский лепет, о котором не стоит даже упоминать. Помещайте на здоровье, если ваша программа ориентирована на такие платформы. В то же время существуют платформы с существенно более ограниченными ресурсами (embedded и т.п.) и там ситуация совсем другая.

В-третьих, пиковое потребление стека вашей программой будет зависеть и от структуры вызовов функций в вашем коде. Если вы разместите 4К объект локально в некоторой рекурсивной функции, глубина вызовов которой может быть большой, то понятно, что 4К будет умножаться на глубину вызовов и общее потребление стековой памяти будет быстро расти. Но, опять же, это не ваша забота, т.е. не забота вашего класса. Это забота автора рекурсивной функции.

В-четвертых, подобные решения сильно зависят от характера кода, который вы пишете. Если вы пишете класс для некоей библиотеки, т.е. код, который потом будет использоваться кем-то другим в некоем конечном приложении, то, понятное дело, не стоит в вашем коде вести себя расточительно по отношению к стековой памяти. А если же вы пишете класс для вашего собственного завершенного приложения, т.е. имеете перед собой полную картину использования памяти и полный над ней контроль, то никто вам не мешает использовать стековую память "не всю катушку".

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае сказать ничего нельзя - но обычно такой подход неправильный. Задумайтесь - в ядре Linux потоки имеют всего по 4 Кб стека - а тут вы эти 4 Кб всего одним объектом занимаете.

Нет, если объект, занимающий 4 Кб получился у вас "сам собой" - это нормально. Стек пользовательского режима и десять метров выдержит. Но вот специально переносить объекты из кучи в стек, к тому же "упаковывая" их в пачки по 4 Кб - занятие глупее не придумаешь.

Если нужно поднять скорость выделения памяти в куче - можно найти альтернативные аллокаторы. Вот, к примеру, что я нашел за минуту гугления: https://github.com/cacay/MemoryPool

Comment: Пул для другой задачи, он на случай когда в куче интенсивно создается/удаляется большое количество маленьких объектов

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, со стеком работа идет быстрее чем с кучой и 4 кб это вообще мизер для сегодняшних мерок и нет никакой опасности с выделения памяти

Comment: Стек быстрее только в части выделения\освобождения. В остальном разницы нет никакой, так что Ваше утверждение весьма спорно.

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее использовать STL + свой аллокатор памяти где можно единожды выделить большой блок памяти из heap и потом его повторно интенсивно использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если 100% не будет больше 4КБ данных, то да. Иначе выделите место в куче. Выделяйте большими кусками, если нужна производительность.